# establishing SSTP VPN connection using sstp-client via command line

Tags: command-line, 16.04, vpn

I have installed `sstp-client` on UBUNTU 16.04 server, and I want to know how to configure `sstp-client` using command line interface.

There are many guides available on net for GUI based control, 
But my server is on AWS and I want to know how can I do this remotely.

Comment: have you tried `man sstpc` and/or `sstpc -help` ?

Comment: You might find [this resource](https://sourceforge.net/p/sstp-client/discussion/1499218/) useful.

Comment: Hope this help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148320/configuring-sstp-client-on-debian

Comment: You can try creating a configuration file with network-manager in an Ubuntu machine in which you have GUI access. You then copy the configuration file from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connetions/vpn-conf-file to your server. In the server, you can use `nmcli con up id vpn-conf-file` to run your vpn. Not that you will need to install network-manager-sstp plug-in in your server first.